# What is correct xmlns url for AdMob in Android Layout XML

Tags: android, testing, sdk, admob

I am testing the AdMob for Android SDK. I can't set the `admob:testing="true"` because the admob attribute is unknown.

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:admob="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/org.ifies.android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:background="#FF000000"
  android:clickable="true"
>
  <com.admob.android.ads.AdView  
    android:id="@+id/admob" 
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="100px"
    android:background="#FF0000"
    admob:testing="true"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

My Eclipse is complaining that `admob:testing="true"` would have an unknown prefix. Anyone got an idea on how to fix this?

Sub question: Anyone got an idea how to change the height of the ad? It seems to be fixed to 48px, which is not looking good on any DROID phone...

Comment: I only manage to set it to testmode by code using the static function AdManager.setInTestMode(true);

Comment: What's happen if you try with another namespace ? (e.g. xmlns:foo).

Comment: I get this error : No resource identifier found for attribute 'testing' in package 'org.ifies.android' itemdetail.xml android/res/layout line 21 Android AAPT Problem

Comment: Have you change the both namespaces ? I mean the declaration `xmlns:foo="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/org.ifies.android"` and the attribute `"foo:testing="true"`

Comment: Yep, changed both, didnt work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Might be worth checking that the error isn't due to something outside the file:

Make sure the package name you are using in your schema URI, "org.ifies.android", matches the value of the package attribute on the manifest element in AndroidManifest.xml.

Make sure res/values/attrs.xml has the attributes specified:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="com.admob.android.ads.AdView">
        <attr name="testing" format="boolean" />
        <attr name="backgroundColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="textColor" format="color" />
        <attr name="keywords" format="string" />
        <attr name="refreshInterval" format="integer" />
        <attr name="isGoneWithoutAd" format="boolean" />
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

Comment: that fixed my noobish mistake.

Comment: Would also like to add, make sure that the attrs.xml actually has the attributes you are trying to use. Different places have different variables!

Answer (score 9):

This took me a while to figure out, so I am posting it here:

Since AdMob 4.1 this has changed, so the previous answer is correct for versions <=4.04. Now you need to use:

```
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
```

No place for your own package in the new schema and no need for an attrs.xml file.

Details here: http://groups.google.com/group/google-admob-ads-sdk/browse_thread/thread/3b885d3fe5bb21a5?pli=1 (Tim's post, it's the 8th from the top)