# Add an AdMob Ad above a TabbedView?

Tags: android, view, ads, tabbed

I am getting an "Error parsing XML file: Unbound prefix" when I try to put my AdMob ad reference above a tabbed view.  Any ideas how to fix that?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:padding="5dp">
        <com.admob.android.ads.AdView android:id="@+id/ad"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            myapp:backgroundColor="#000000" myapp:primaryTextColor="#FFFFFF"
            myapp:secondaryTextColor="#CCCCCC" />
        <TabWidget android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <FrameLayout android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="5dp" />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using this:

```
myapp:backgroundColor
```

but I don't see any declaration of the 'myapp' prefix. so that might be the source of the error.

Just like the "android" namespace is declared in the xml like this:

```
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
```

the 'myapp' namespace should have a declaration somewhere also

Comment: Of course you're right and I completely missed it.  *sigh*  Thank you.  That's the problem with working between projects ... xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.package.namespace"

Comment: :) Why do you think I knew it -> Have done my share of this ;) .... mostly not declaring the android: prefix, or declaring it too late :)

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020542/what-is-correct-xmlns-url-for-admob-in-android-layout-xml) seems related.

You need both the `xmlns` set correctly, as Nanne said, as well as your attributes defined in `res/style/attrs.xml`.

The `xmlns` appears to be:

`xmlns:admob="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.package"`

For an example `attrs.xml`, check out the answer above.

Comment: Also correct.  Fortunately I was modifying my existing project to have a tabbed interface so the attrs.xml already exists.  Would have certainly tripped me up otherwise.