# Android AdMob FULL XML NAMESPACE published anywhere?

Tags: android, xml, namespaces, admob

I am trying to use AdMob, and have found all sorts of out of date information (pre 4.0)

What I am trying to find out is there a full copy of the XML Namespace that comes in the Jar anywhere?

I'd like to know what my setting options are in XML configurations for the AdView in the layout XML.. but to date I haven't been able to find it.

Does this exist?

Answer (score 2):

I added that info not so long ago to an old question here: [What is correct xmlns url for AdMob in Android Layout XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020542/what-is-correct-xmlns-url-for-admob-in-android-layout-xml/6092776#6092776)

In short, you need: `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"`

BTW, you don't need to add an entry `<declare-styleable>` in res/values/attrs.xml anymore.

Comment: Yes I know that is the include... but is the actual XLMNS file published or documented anywhere so we know the options are allowable and valid and what they do.

Comment: All I can do is to quote this reply to the thread I linked in the other response: "Sorry for the inconvenience. We haven't had a chance to update all of our documentation fully yet. 4.1.0 made some changes to the way that XML layouts work. In particular, you shouldn't need attrs.xml anymore. ". It's a month old, but I don't see any change in the docs since then. I am assuming we can use the same attrs as before.